# Kaplan-Meier for interval-censoring data

Tags: kaplan-meier, interval-censoring

I would like to ask if someone encountered the problem with a specific form of interval data in survival analysis. 
How to perform the preliminary analysis (for instance Kaplan-Meier estimator) of survival time when each of my observations has its own time interval? 
 
The first five examples:

```
+----+------+--------+----------+
| Id | Left | Right  | Censored |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  1 |    0 |      1 |        0 |
|  1 |    2 |     17 |        1 |
|  2 |    0 |      7 |        0 |
|  3 |    0 |      3 |        0 |
|  3 |    4 |     34 |        1 |
+----+------+--------+----------+
```

Left - begining of compartment 
Right -  end of compartment

Comment: For variable ``censored``, 0 = censored or 1 = censored?

Comment: @user158565, this is an abortive term: 0 = censored. Thanks

Comment: Then you just need to keep one record for each id. For example, keep 0 17 1 for id =1, 0 34 1 for id =3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you talk about ***survival time***, you'll need to compute the time interval (`tInt = Right - Left`) for each `Id` and use that new variable to obtain a Kaplan-Meier estimator.

Afterwards, if you want to do something like a Cox regression, besides the time interval `tInt` you may also use as one covariate either the middle time point `mtp = (Left + Right) / 2` or the initial time (`Left`). The middle time point `mtp` might be a better covariate since it's usually less correlated with the time interval `tInt`.